# Como desligo a indentação do kotlin e do java no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, indentação

Estava fazendo um projeto e ocorreu um erro no Android Studio fechando o mesmo, quando abri novamente o meu código estava indentado com a identação padrão da IDE, queria saber como desativar isso, deixar ela manual.

Answer (score -3):

Salve, já tentou o comando Control + Alt + L?